# lambda shows `GetSecretValue operation: Access to KMS is not allowed`

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Lambda shows this error in log `GetSecretValue operation: Access to KMS is not allowed`

I am not sure where lambda uses `KMS`(not in program..) though

I gave `AWSKeyManagementServicePowerUser` to lambda exec roll.

However still have same error.

How can I fix this?

---

Role for secrets manager is set and shown in resource summary of lambda

```
arn:aws:secretsmanager:ap-northeast-1:665852222222:secret:vr-stag-rds-secret-key-Xb97EV 
Allow: secretsmanager:GetSecretValue
Allow: secretsmanager:DescribeSecret
```

However error occcurs `Error when try to get the secret vr-stag-rds-secret-key in ap-northeast-1.`

in this source code.

```
session = boto3.session.Session()
client = session.client(service_name='secretsmanager', region_name=region_name)
logger.info(f"try to fetch secret {secret_name} in {region_name}. ")
try:
    get_secret_value_response = client.get_secret_value(SecretId=secret_name)
except Exception as e:
    logger.error(f"Error when try to get secret {secret_name} in {region_name}. ")
    logger.exception(e)
    raise e
```

and this error also occurs it doesn't use KMS though.

```
{
    "level": "ERROR",
    "location": "fetch_secret:21",
    "message": "An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the GetSecretValue operation: Access to KMS is not allowed",
    "timestamp": "2022-04-11 04:49:28,586+0000",
    "service": "lambda-web",
    "exception": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/var/task/.build/vr/utilities/fetch_secret.py\", line 18, in fetch_secret\n    get_secret_value_response = client.get_secret_value(SecretId=secret_name)\n  File \"/var/task/botocore/client.py\", line 401, in _api_call\n    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)\n  File \"/var/task/botocore/client.py\", line 731, in _make_api_call\n    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)\nbotocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the GetSecretValue operation: Access to KMS is not allowed",
    "exception_name": "ClientError"
}
```

---

**Conclusion**

The problem occurs when secret manager is encrypted by encryption key in `KMS`, even the programs on `lambda` requires access only `secret-manager`.

Lambda also requires the both permission to `secret-key` in `secret-manager`  and `encryption-key` in `KMS`

Comment: Are you using Secrets Manager?

Comment: @Marcin Yes I am using secrets manager. I access from secrets manager from the program.

Comment: AH, I see this error shows KMS but ,error happens when fetching the key from secret manager. However my lambda has access policy in role document..

Comment: You would have to show the role. Its difficult to speculate.

Comment: I updated the article, at first it fails to get the secret manager, and shows the error `Access to KMS is not allowed`,in my understanding secret manager is not KMS. so, is it related?

Comment: Your secrets can be encrypted, which requires access to KMS to decrypt them.

Comment: Ah you are right !! I found in the console of key in secret manager encripution key `vr-stag-common-encryption-key`.

Comment: So, did you manage to solve the access issue?

Comment: I updated this article and write conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

> Secrets Manager integrates with AWS Key Management Service (AWS KMS) to encrypt every version of every secret value with a unique data key that is protected by an AWS KMS key. This integration protects your secrets under encryption keys that never leave AWS KMS unencrypted. It also enables you to set custom permissions on the KMS key and audit the operations that generate, encrypt, and decrypt the data keys that protect your secrets.

When using KMS to encrypt your secrets, it's important than any service/code trying to access those secrets also has access to your KMS key, in order to decrypt the secret.

More information can be found here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/security-encryption.html